# UIButton that has an interupptable animation with UIViewPropertyAnimator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, button

I want a button to expand (Scale up) when the user touches the button, and shrink back to normal when the touch leaves. Similar to iOS stock calculator before iOS 11. This is the class that I created a subclass of the button. It uses touchesbegan and touchesended to start, and or pause and revers the animation, but it does not shrink properly, and it doesn't animate.

```
class UIOutlineButton: UIButton {

var squishAnimation:UIPropertyAnimator!

override public func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)



    squishAnimation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, dampingRatio: 30, animations: {
        let scale = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.8, y: 0.8)

        let rotate = self.transform.rotated(by: 0.3)
        self.transform.concatenating(rotate)
        self.transform = scale
    })
    squishAnimation.isReversed = true
    squishAnimation.startAnimation()


    self.next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

}

override public func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    colorAnimation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, dampingRatio: 30, animations: {


    })

    squishAnimation = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 0.5, dampingRatio: 30, animations: {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    })

    squishAnimation.stopAnimation(true)

    squishAnimation.startAnimation()
}


}
```

Comment: Ok, so break it down into steps. Can you use a touch down inside event to trigger the growth? And then touch up inside + touch up outside to shrink it back to normal?

For the animations, take a look at UIView methods like `animate(duration:animations)`. See if you can work it out. If not, post your code and tell us how it fails to meet your needs and we'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an little snippet which will 'grow' a UIView and then return it to it's original size after a short delay:

```
  /// Expands & Then Returns A UIView To It's Original Size
  ///
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - view: UIView
  ///   - duration: Double
  ///   - enable: (Void)
  func animate(view: UIView, duration: Double, enable: @escaping () -> ()){

       view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

       UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {

           view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.8, y: 0.8)

       }) { (continueSequence) in

           UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, animations: {

                view.transform = .identity

           }, completion: { (seqeunceFinished) in
               enable()
        })
      }
   }
```

You can then call it within an IBAction as follows:

```
@IBAction func enlargeButton(_ sender: UIButton){

      sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

      enlarge(view: sender duration: 1) { sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = true }
}
```

Comment: This is the right concept, however, I want the animation to be interruptable, this snippet animates the change, but it cannot be interrupted, the animation must complete before any change can happen to it.

Comment: I have updated the code to disable the button when it is touched, and then re-enabled it when the completion handler is called.

Comment: I've updated my post to clarify what I want to accomplish, the animation should be able to be stopped in the middle of it's process, and reverse if needed if the user interrupts the in the middle of the animation.